# How to solve my Error

Tags: asp.net

i have click the radio button1 the disable the text box. the radio button2 click

the text box is enable but first i have click radio button2 and then i have click radio button1 not disable the text box How to solve the problem
`enter code here`

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
               txtrb.Enabled = true;
            }

        }


    protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            if (RadioButton1.Enabled == true )
            {
                txtrb.Enabled = false ;
            }

        }
    }

    protected void RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RadioButton2.Enabled == true)
        {
            txtrb.Enabled = true ;
        }


    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please write your problem clearly, we not understand what you want. Edit your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check

if (RadioButton1.**checked** == true ) and if (RadioButton2.**checked**== true )